# Should the index page have the sign up page or login page?

Tags: user-expectation, login

First of all, I don't want the *Sign Up form* and *Login form* to be on the same page, like [Facebook](http://facebook.com).

[image: #1 Visual Aid]

I want some clean organization. To continue, I want at least one form on the index page. I don't want to do something like Stack Overflow and have no forms and only a sign up message.

[image: #2 Visual Aid]

On **Twitter** the *Login Form* is on the index page.

[image: #3 Visual Aid]

On **Evernote** the *Sign Up Form* is on the index page.

[image: #4 Visual Aid]

What's the best strategy?

Comment: What if the "best strategy" is one of those you don't want? I'm pretty sure Facebook tested this extensively (well, I know for a fact), and same goes fro Twitter. And I assume Evernote did the same with its approach, so different approaches may work and no answer is correct unless you provide A LOT more information, including user testing, tracking and such so we can compare. As it stands... choose whatever option you like and test it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it all boils down to who you want to make happy.

If a new user comes across your page and is presented with a Sign up sheet, they're obviously going to be more inclined to sign up, rather than if they had to go hunting for a button.

Then again, users coming back to the page are going to be a little more frustrated having to head to a second page to log in (myself included). BUT they're already signed up and in your community, so it's little deterrent for returning users.

So yeah,

New users -> sign up | keeping people happy -> login.

Comment: Nice thoughts. Would you mind elaborating with some research on the topic? In case your wondering, I'm creating a sweepstakes company...

Comment: +1 Though bear in mind that many users will have "remember me" turned on (I'm an exception to this on most sites), so will hardly ever run into the frustration of hunting for / navigating to a login page. That said: the less frequently you use something important, the more it needs to be obviously available.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a mix of both? You can track repeat visits and know if a browser is returning to your site based on IP address. It's not perfect, but you'll be able to A/B test the hell out of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you force users to sign then go with Facebook's Strategy, or you can use a modal mentioning the benefits of signing up with your websites, and a button to sign up, Don't forget to place a **close button** or you can use click anywhere to close modal.

Using modal you have many benefits:

1. User will be aware the benefits you are providing.
2. This gives you a clean landing page, you can also place a sign up button on index page.

For more benefits refer [this](http://www.copyblogger.com/pop-ups/).